# Make ancestor flexbox divs only take up the width of its child with a set width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have an input element using flex display and I set its `flex-basis` width like so:

```
.flex-row input { flex: 0 1 450px; }
```

and a `flex-row` div is contained inside of a `flex-container` div.

I want the `flex-row` to only take up the width that the input takes.

When I give `flex-container` `display: flex` it takes up 100% width.

When I give it `display: inline-flex` it compresses the input making it much smaller than 450px.

I don't really care about the width of `flex-container`, although it would be nice for it to take up the width of its child as well, but how do I make `flex-row` have the same width as the input (namely, when there is enough room for it, 450px)?

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
}
.flex-row {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.flex-row input {
  flex: 0 1 450px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-row">
    <input type="text" name="query" class="searchbar" />
  </div>
</div>
```

and [here](https://jsfiddle.net/5wksaj72/1/) is a fiddle example.

Comment: Have you considered making the `flex-row` be 450px, and then having the child input simply fill it up with `flex: 1`? https://jsfiddle.net/5wksaj72/2/

Comment: I did but my html is a bit more complicated than this. I have multiple objects, not just an input element, inside of multiple flex-rows.

Comment: @Michael_B maybe I should update my question, but [here](https://jsfiddle.net/5wksaj72/3/) is a more accurate picture of what my situation looks like although I guess [this](https://jsfiddle.net/5wksaj72/4/) works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the same flex property to the flex-row as you have on the flex-row input.

```
.flex-row{
    display: flex;
    flex: 0 1 450px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

If you want the row to be centered as well then add the align and justify properties to the flex-container as follows.

```
.flex-container{
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: so what you're suggesting is also putting the flex-basis on the flex-row instead of the input?

Comment: Yes. That is the only way you can control both the row and the input to keep themselfs flexible and of the width 450px even when there is much space there. I believe this answer serves what you asked. If not then i may have miss understood. Please do let me know and i can help.